# as3 how to remove/ move position of graphics from reset array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, graphics, for-loop

I am trying to reset a scene an move every thing to its original position the reset function resets the array adds the nape bodies back to the stage and attaches the graphics but the original graphics still are on the stage in whatever position they were in when reset was called

```
private var brickGraphic:MovieClip = new Brick();
private var brick:Body;
private var brickArray:Array;

private function setUp():void
{
    brickArray = new Array  ;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var brick:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
        var brickShape:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(10,25));
        var brickGraphic = new Brick();
        brickGraphic.width = 10;
        brickGraphic.height = 25;
        addChild(brickGraphic);
        brickGraphic.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        brick.shapes.add(brickShape);
        brick.position.setxy(450, ((ag ) - 30 * (i + 0.5)));
        brick.angularVel = 0;
        brick.shapes.at(0).material.elasticity = .5;
        brick.shapes.at(0).material.density = 150;
        brick.cbTypes.add(brickType);
        brick.space = space;
        brickGraphic.stop();
        brick.userData.sprite = brickGraphic;
        brick.userData.sprite.x = brick.position.x;
        this.brickArray.push(brick);
    }

    private function reset():void
    {
        if (contains(brickGraphic)) removeChild(brickGraphic);
        space.clear();
        setUp();
    }
}
```

this is the final issue i am having on this app and your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not removing them with `removeChild`.

You need to call `removeChild` for each `brickGraphic` object you add to the stage.

Something like :

```
private function setUp():void
{
    brickArray = [];

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var brick:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
        var brickShape:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(10,25));
        var brickGraphic = new Brick();
        brickGraphic.width = 10;
        brickGraphic.height = 25;
        addChild(brickGraphic);
        brickGraphic.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        brick.shapes.add(brickShape);
        brick.position.setxy(450, ((ag ) - 30 * (i + 0.5)));
        brick.angularVel = 0;
        brick.shapes.at(0).material.elasticity = .5;
        brick.shapes.at(0).material.density = 150;
        brick.cbTypes.add(brickType);
        brick.space = space;
        brickGraphic.stop();
        brick.userData.sprite = brickGraphic;
        brick.userData.sprite.x = brick.position.x;
        this.brickArray.push(brick);
    }


}

private function removeAllBricks():void
{
    for(var i:int=0; i<brickArray.length; i++)
    {
       var dp:DisplayObject = brickArray[i].userData.sprite as DisplayObject;
       if(dp && dp.parent)
           dp.parent.removeChild(dp);
    }
}

private function reset():void
{
    removeAllBricks();
    space.clear();
    setUp();
}
```

Comment: that returned the following arror `TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.` and points to the line that the reset function is called

Comment: i treced out : `trace(brickArray[r].shapes.at(0) as DisplayObject);` and it returned null 10 times.

Comment: Modified my answer, and added checks to make sure the display objects have parents incase the funcion is called before setup.

Comment: Modified again I saw you store the `brickGraphic` under userData.